# Problem while integrating GPS data into robot_localization

Tags: navigation, ekf, gps, navsat-transform-node, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to Tom and everybody,

I'm currently making some experiments with robot_localization, and I'm having some problems with the integration of GPS data for global localization of a non-holonomic mobile robot constrained to a 2D plane (no Z coordinate and no roll/pitch).

Here is the overview of my setup for odometry which is very similar to the one described in [this section](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/integrating_gps.html#notes-on-fusing-gps-data) of the wiki where the use of a dual EKF node is discussed.

[image: Odometry overview]

- X and Y are bidimensional coordinates
- Vx and Vy are linear velocities
- H^, X^^ and Y^^ are angular velocity and linear accelerations, respectively
- The topic name is inside parentheses
- The provided TF transformation is inside square brackets

This is my **launch file** (only the part relevant to replay the bag file):

```
<launch>

<!-- Reference frames -->
<arg name="world_frame"  default="earth"/>
<arg name="map_frame"    default="map_link"/>
<arg name="odom_frame"   default="odom_link"/>
<arg name="robot_frame"  default="base_link"/>
<arg name="camera_frame" default="camera_link"/>

<!-- Odometry topics -->
<arg name="wheels_odom"  default="/odometry/wheels"/>
<arg name="imu_odom"     default="/odometry/imu"/>
<arg name="gps_odom"     default="/odometry/gps"/>
<arg name="navsat_odom"  default="/odometry/navsat"/>
<arg name="visual_odom"  default="/odometry/visual"/>
<arg name="local_odom"   default="/odometry/local"/>
<arg name="global_odom"  default="/odometry/global"/>

<!-- Sensor fusion 1 -->
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf1_local" clear_params="true" output="screen">
    <param name="frequency"         value="50"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout"    value="0.2"/>
    <param name="two_d_mode"        value="true"/>
    <param name="map_frame"         value="$(arg map_frame)"/>
    <param name="odom_frame"        value="$(arg odom_frame)"/>
    <param name="base_link_frame"   value="$(arg robot_frame)"/>
    <param name="world_frame"       value="$(arg odom_frame)"/>

    <param name="use_control"       value="false"/>
    <param name="print_diagnostics" value="true"/>
    <param name="debug"             value="false"/>
    <param name="debug_out_file"    value="~/Log/ekf1.txt"/>

    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="$(arg local_odom)"/>

    <param name="odom0" value="$(arg wheels_odom)"/>
    <rosparam param="odom0_config">
        [ false, false, false,
          false, false, false,
          true,  true,  false,
          false, false, false,
          false, false, false ]
    </rosparam>
    <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
    <param name="odom0_relative"     value="false"/>
    <param name="odom0_queue_size"   value="10"/>
    <param name="odom0_nodelay"      value="true"/>

    <param name="imu0" value="$(arg imu_odom)"/>
    <rosparam param="imu0_config">
        [ false, false, false,
          false, false, false,
          false, false, false,
          false, false, true,
          true,  true,  false ]
    </rosparam>
    <param name="imu0_differential" value="false"/>
    <param name="imu0_relative"     value="false"/>
    <param name="imu0_queue_size"   value="10"/>
    <param name="imu0_nodelay"      value="false"/>
    <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="false"/>
</node>

<!-- GPS coordinates transformation -->
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform" clear_params="true" output="screen">
    <param name="frequency"            value="20"/>
    <param name="yaw_offset"           value="1.570796327"/>
    <param name="zero_altitude"        value="true"/>
    <param name="publish_filtered_gps" value="false"/>
    <param name="use_odometry_yaw"     value="false"/>
    <param name="wait_for_datum"       value="true"/>
    <param name="broadcast_utm_transform" value="false"/>
    <param name="delay"                value="3"/>
    <param name="magnetic_declination_radians" value="0.00383972"/>
    <rosparam param="datum">[43.542883, 11.571365, 0]</rosparam>

    <remap from="imu/data"          to="$(arg imu_odom)"/>
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="$(arg local_odom)"/>
    <remap from="gps/fix"           to="$(arg gps_odom)"/>
    <remap from="odometry/gps"      to="$(arg navsat_odom)"/>
</node>

<!-- Sensor fusion 2 -->
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf2_global" clear_params="true" output="screen">
    <param name="frequency"         value="10"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout"    value="0.2"/>
    <param name="two_d_mode"        value="true"/>
    <param name="map_frame"         value="$(arg map_frame)"/>
    <param name="odom_frame"        value="$(arg odom_frame)"/>
    <param name="base_link_frame"   value="$(arg robot_frame)"/>
    <param name="world_frame"       value="$(arg map_frame)"/>

    <param name="use_control"       value="false"/>
    <param name="print_diagnostics" value="true"/>
    <param name="debug"             value="false"/>
    <param name="debug_out_file"    value="~/Log/ekf2.txt"/>

    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="$(arg global_odom)"/>

    <param name="odom0" value="$(arg wheels_odom)"/>
    <rosparam param="odom0_config">
        [ false, false, false,
          false, false, false,
          true,  true,  false,
          false, false, false,
          false, false, false ]
    </rosparam>
    <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
    <param name="odom0_relative"     value="false"/>
    <param name="odom0_queue_size"   value="10"/>
    <param name="odom0_nodelay"      value="true"/>

    <param name="odom1" value="$(arg navsat_odom)"/>
    <rosparam param="odom1_config">
        [ true,  true,  false,
          false, false, false,
          false, false, false,
          false, false, false,
          false, false, false ]
    </rosparam>
    <param name="odom1_differential" value="false"/>
    <param name="odom1_relative"     value="false"/>
    <param name="odom1_queue_size"   value="10"/>
    <param name="odom1_nodelay"      value="true"/>

    <param name="imu0" value="$(arg imu_odom)"/>
    <rosparam param="imu0_config">
        [ false, false, false,
          false, false, false,
          false, false, false,
          false, false, true,
          true,  true,  false ]
    </rosparam>
    <param name="imu0_differential" value="false"/>
    <param name="imu0_relative"     value="false"/>
    <param name="imu0_queue_size"   value="10"/>
    <param name="imu0_nodelay"      value="false"/>
    <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="false"/>
</node>
```

And below there is the output of `rqt_graph` which I suppose it's correct, except I don't know why "navsat_transform" is not subscribed to topic "/odometry/imu" even if I specified it with a remap.

[image description http://i67.tinypic.com/2wgw3h1.jpg](http://i67.tinypic.com/2wgw3h1.jpg)

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bljxrfje7xgmp52/data.bag?dl=0) is the link to download the **bag file** that can be used with the above launch file.

When launched, this is the TF tree I'm seeing with `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree` that makes sense to me.

[TF http://i68.tinypic.com/iy0ob5.jpg](http://i68.tinypic.com/iy0ob5.jpg)

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6yguf9f9779inja/odometry.rviz?dl=0) you can download the RVIZ config file to obtain the same visualization I'm using.

While replaying the bag file, the `odom_link-->base_link` transformation is correctly calculated by the Kalman filter (I'm having pretty good accuracy, too!), but it seems there are problems with the `map-->odom` transformation, because I see these warnings multiple times:

```
[ WARN] [1485356716.681560393]: Transform from odom_link to map_link was unavailable for the time requested. Using latest instead.
[ WARN] [1485356718.683456544]: Transform from map_link to base_link was unavailable for the time requested. Using latest instead.
```

Other than that, the estimated global pose start diverging after a few seconds and the coordinates become huge, it is not so clear in the following image, but this is what I see in RVIZ after setting "map" as the fixed frame.

[Map http://i67.tinypic.com/281zqya.jpg](http://i67.tinypic.com/281zqya.jpg)

I would like to obtain something similar to what was presented by Tom here, but the GPS data is giving a really unpredictable behavior.

Does anybody having these kind of issues with a similar setup?

Many thanks,
Guido

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252997/problem-while-integrating-gps-data-into-robot_localization/) by [GuidoBartoli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25445/guidobartoli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-01-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the nicely formatted question! I'm not positive this will do anything, but before I start looking at bag files, I do see that your `navsat_transform_node` instance is listening to the wrong EKF output. `navsat_transform_node` will work with a two-level EKF setup, but doesn't require it, so this line in your `navsat_transform_node` configuration:

```
<remap from="odometry/filtered" to="$(arg local_odom)"/>
```

should be

```
<remap from="odometry/filtered" to="$(arg global_odom)"/>
```

The circular dependency between `navsat_transform_node` and the EKF is intentional. Again, I'm not sure that's your issue, but we should fix it before continuing.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I set the input of navsat to the output of the second EKF, the situation is a little better, i.e. setting `map_link` as fixed in RVIZ, I can see `odom-->base` TF remaining consistent as before, since it comes from the first EKF, but `map_link-->odom_link` stays a bit closer to the real trajectory, even if after a bit it still diverges very much, even if it seems the raw GPS data are not so noisy.

So, the overview graph is now like that?

[image description http://i66.tinypic.com/11kfrio.jpg](http://i66.tinypic.com/11kfrio.jpg)

Some more questions about this setup:

- With your correction, the first warning about `odom-->map` transform disappeared, but the second one about `map-->base` is still there. I have GPS data produced at about 1Hz, do I have to change **navsat** frequency to a lower value?
- I also tried to set `use_odometry_yaw="true"` in **navsat** parameters, but from the node graph it still seems not using the IMU orientation for creating `/odometry/navsat`. Is this an intended behavior?
- If I have understood well, looping `/odometry/global` into **navsat** and keeping `/odometry/local` separate from it have the effect of the first one producing `map-->odom` and the second `odom-->base` independently, right? This concept is still a bit obscure to me after reading [this](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/integrating_gps.html#notes-on-fusing-gps-data) and your dual_ekf ROS example... :(
- The topic `/odometry/global` from the second EKF has `frame_id = map` and `child_frame_id = base_link`. Should not the second be equal to `odom`?
- A small note, in [this](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/integrating_gps.html#required-inputs) wiki page, you mention the `datum` parameter has 5 arguments, but it seems the latest version accepts only the first 3, frames are not necessary.

Thanks,

Guido

---

Originally posted by [GuidoBartoli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25445/guidobartoli/) with karma: 31 on 2017-01-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-02-01**:
This is an excellent graph with good questions; can you please edit the original question with this information? They try to avoid turning these questions into threads.